# Javascript: finding frame on mainPage from the popups?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, frames

In the following Javascript I have to keep finding the mainFrame from the Popup pages, is there a better way to do this?

```
function sendRefreshMessage(data) {
    var myObj = null;
    myObj = document.getElementById('slPlugin');
    if (null != myObj) {
        try {
            //perform operation on myObj
        } catch (err) {
        }
    }
    else {
        if (null != top.opener.top.mainFrame) {
            myObj = top.opener.top.mainFrame.document.getElementById('slPlugin');
            if (null != myObj) {
                try {
                    //perform operation on myObj
                } catch (err) {
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            myObj = top.opener.top.opener.top.mainFrame.document.getElementById('slPlugin');
            if (null != myObj) {
                try {
                    //perform operation on myObj
                } catch (err) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's a cleaner (but not necessarily *better*) way to do that, assuming your plugin always resides inside an element called `mainFrame`:

```
function findPlugin(container)
{
    var plugin = null;
    if (container.mainFrame != null) {
        plugin = container.mainFrame.document.getElementById('slPlugin');
    }
    if (plugin == null && container.opener != null) {
        plugin = findPlugin(container.opener.top);
    }
    return plugin;
}

function sendRefreshMessage(data)
{
    var plugin = findPlugin(window.top);
    if (plugin != null) {
        try {
            // Perform operation on `plugin`.
        } catch (err) {
            // Please avoid empty catch blocks, they're evil.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I only had the empty catch blocks because I would get a JavaScript error if the operation on the plugin failed.